# I'm trying to create an url_for in an html <img src=...> tag where the filename for the image is stored in a variable. How would I do this?

Tags: flask, jinja2

I am trying to create a page for users that will display their profile pic and I've retrieved the picture filename from a database and stored that filename as a variable called "profilePic".

I've passed profilePic to the html page as a variable, but how would I create the `<img>` tag using Jinja2's {{ url_for }}.  I know how to do it if I just type in the picname, but in this case the pic's name changes from user to user.

I tried...

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/user/{{ profilePic }}' }}>
```

which does not work because it appears you cannot nest {{ }} items in Jinja2.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can just perform normal string concatenation in your template using `+`

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='/img/user/' + profilePic) }}" />
```

or `.join`

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='/'.join(['img', 'user', profilePic])) }}" />
```

Comment: Thanks that worked beautifully.  It appears I was overthinking this problem.  I didn't realize it would automatically replace the variable name with it's value in this situation.

Comment: I'm new to this site and not sure how to give you credit for giving me the exact answer I was looking for.

Comment: @RobertB If this worked for you, you can accept the answer by selecting the green checkmark to the left of the answer.

Comment: @Suever it doesn't work for me, the variable name inside {{ }} is treated as string.

Comment: @danishansari Are you calling `render_template` from your view? Not sure that was worth a downvote :)